# Wordpress post visible only those with a link

Tags: privacy

I posted this question here because it is regarding security.
I wanted to know is there any way to WordPress post be only visible when someone has a link. And not to be shown in search or recent posts.
I am asking this because i own english-only website and I wish to post something in my language and share link within my country so that other english visitors do not be confused with article on Serbian language.

Regards

Comment: I flagged this for moderation attention asking to have this post migrated to that site.

Comment: Thank you, i was just about to ask that, because i tried removing post here and posting it there. but i have some 40min limit. Thanks!

Comment: BY default there is no such way to keep posts private the way you are trying.

Can we create a taxonomy and assign those posts to that taxonomy ,than  exclude that taxonomy from search and other listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real solution to my question is to install UCE (Ultimate Category Excluder)
which allows me to exclude post for showing in front page, feeds, archives, and search results.
I can choose where I want it to show, if I do.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/

Answer (score 0):

You should select "**Password-protected**" below the post PUBLISH button. (Or **PRIVATE**, if sharing only with logged-in users).

Comment: Not solutions to my problem.